# How do you manually hot reload Flutter

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, signals, flutter-plugin

Im writing a node js app to manipulate Flutter code by adding lines of code to it. I want to see updates in real time. Is it possible to somehow hot reload Everytime I'm done writing a line in the file? I'm using visual studio code. I've tried using robot.js to simulate key press but those send keys to the nodejs terminal and not to Flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_hotreload/versions/0.2.0 works for me to make my Dart server app reload itself every time a file changes.

On GitHub is a Dart2 compatible version. I don't know why they didn't publish it yet, but you can use it from there.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm stuck on an error. "Because project_name depends on flutter any from sdk which doesn't exist (unknown SDK "flutter'"), version solving failed." I'm can't get rid of it.

Comment: Not enough information. Please add pubspec.yaml to your questin.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my pubspec.yaml

Comment: flutter packages get

Comment: Weird. You have a `'` at the end of `flutter'` that looks wrong. Compare it with the pubspec.yaml of another project to see how it should look like. Also your approach can't work because the code runs on a device or emulator and can't see file changes on your developer machine. You'd need an extra process that does the file watching and invoking hot-reload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182196/discussion-between-prince-hodonou-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Hello, I was able to set up a file watcher and it reloads when the file specified is changed. However, the actual app on the emulator isn't reloading. How do I get the watcher to actually re-render the app?

Comment: You probably are reloading the project that runs jaguar_hotreload, but that is unrelated to Flutter. You can pass an alternative `vmServiceUrl` to `HotReloader` and that one needs to point to the mobile device and the Dart instance running there. It should print the service port when it is started.